# Change from (0,1 microdegree) to degree

Tags: unit-of-measure

I am trying to implement some code and I need change the units of the latitude, longitude that I recive from a CAM message which standard is described here [ETSI Standard](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102800_102899/10289402/01.02.01_60/ts_10289402v010201p.pdf).

It says that the latitude and longitude is especified as (0,1 degree) but I need to use it as degree. As (0,1 degree) is quite confusing and I don't know how to change it.

How can I calculate the change?

Comment: (For those who care, as a rule of thumb $0.1\,\mu^\circ\approx 1\,\text{cm}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the change in tenths of microdegrees, then divide by $10^7$ to express the change in degrees.

To go the other way (degrees to tenths of microdegrees), multiply by $10^7$.

There are $10$ tenths of microdegrees in one microdegree, and $10^6$ microdegrees in a degree. Hence the overall factor is $10 \cdot 10^6 = 10^7.$